# How to structure Laravel projects properly?

Tags: php, laravel, design-patterns

Recently started working with Laravel and have a hard time structuring my project related to the current feature I'm working on.

Basically there exists a Subscription model that contains info about a subscription and most notably contains an expiry date. The feature I'm working on is to automaticze subscription expiry reminders to "customers" and also auto renew if the customer has not unsubscribed.

The problem is that I'm not sure how to structure the logic for this properly. Currently I have created a class called SubscriptionManager that has 2 functions. notifyExpiring ($subscription) and renewExpired ($subscription).

These functions require logic based on the subscription. For example: a customer should only be notified by email if the sub is 2 months from expiring. Where should this function be?

Currently I have it as a static function in
class SubscriptionHelper called isExpiring ($subscription).

As I've understood, logic in a Model class is a no go and I 'm not sure if a Service class is something for this.

Update #1:

````
public static function isExpiring(Subscription $sub)
    {
        $months_until_expiration = $sub->getEndDate()->floatDiffInMonths(Carbon::today());

        if ($months_until_expiration <= 2) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }```
````

Comment: what is the `getEndDate` method for? Does it just retrieve a date model property? Do you have endDates as relationships?

Comment: The getEndDate method just returns a field "end_time" parsed as a Carbon date instead of date + time string.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a Job https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#creating-jobs
containing your subscription logic notification.

In addition, you will have to use schedule https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#defining-schedules for dispatching that Job every some specified time (let's say every 24 hours).

---

EDIT: As per added details in your question, you could improve a few things:

You don't need a method for parsing `end_time` property. For that, you can make use of attribute casting: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting.
So your `end_time` can easily retrieved as Carbon date instance with this:

```
 Subscription.php

/**
* The attributes that should be cast to native types.
*
* @var array
*/
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s',
    'updated_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d H:i:s',
    'end_time' => 'date:Y-m-d'
];
```

On the other hand, for checking if Subscription model is about to expire you can use Accessors https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor and appends https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json in your model:

```
Subscription.php

/**
 * The accessors to append to the model's array form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
 protected $appends = ['is_expiring'];

/**
 * Get the subscription's expiring status.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Casts\Attribute
 */
 protected function isExpiring(): Attribute
 {
    return Attribute::make(
       get: fn () => {
          $months_until_expiration = $this->end_time->floatDiffInMonths(Carbon::today());
          return $months_until_expiration <= 2;
       }
    );
 }
```

Said that you could use a job for checking/dispatching notifications for Subscriptions about to expire

```
NotifyExpiring.php

/**
* Execute the job.
*
* @return void
*/
public function handle()
{
    $subscriptions = Subscription::all();

    foreach($subscriptions as $subscription) {
       if ($subscription->is_expiring) {
          // Do something like dispatching a notification
          ExpiringNotification::dispatch($subscription);
       } else {
          // Do something else
       }
    }
}
```

Please note that this is how I would do it to keep everything as simple as possible, but there may be other ways.

Again, there is no correct way to do this. It all depends on what do you need and if you will need to reuse code.

Comment: Thank you! But where should micro logic for the Subscription model be? For ex. the isExpiring method that just determines if the sub is within 2 months of expiration date.

Comment: I could have a big handle() function in the job class but id like to break down the micro logic instead

Comment: It's hard to say how you should structure your app since I don't know what your logic does. Services or helpers are useful when methods need to be reused by other controllers/jobs/etc. If your micrologic is just a simple computed property you can use model Accessors. Otherwise, you could go for a SubscriptionsController with a main method that invokes other private methods. You may need to elaborate your question with some code to get a better answer

Comment: Thanks again for the advice. I've updated the post with an example of a function where I'm not sure where it belongs. It is currently in the SubscriptionHelper class as a static function.

Comment: Again thank you, very much appreciated. I will definetely implement casts and attributions instead! This was very useful :D